How can I accept xcode license without admin access?
I'm on a machine with zero admin access and zero possibility of obtaining said access. Is there a way for me to accept the license agreement without knowing the admin password?

You can't even fully install Xcode without admin rights, so accepting the license is not really an issue.

I have ways to install the rest, this part is just the most painful.

Is the owner OK with you installing Xcode?

For locked down machines like this ask the administrator how do do the task.
